# Determine if a TextView requires scrolling

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview

Inside `CursorAdapter`'s `bindView()` I bind data to the following layout:

[image]

A `TextView` and two `Button`s : "UP" and "DOWN".

The `TextView` is defined in XML like so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="#5c6284"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="40sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

A vertical scrolling behavior is applied to the `TextView`, which is being controlled by the "UP and "DOWN" `Button`s.

I would like to determine if the `TextView` requires scrolling ( is long enough to not fit its provided drawing area ) so that I can enable/disable the "UP" and "DOWN" buttons accordingly.

I'm currently reading `BaseMovementMethod`'s `scrollDown` function, thinking of applying its measuring logic to my adapter, though I have the feeling that it should be much simpler. Maybe a built in behavior that I'm not aware of.

Is there a better way to achieve this, other than my suggested approach?

Comment: What is the minimum SDKversion for your app?

Comment: The minimum SDK version is 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Static Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) class. If you set it up with your TextView's parameters you'll be able to calculate the height of the rendered text.

```
Layout.Alignment alignment = Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL;
float spacingMultiplier = 1;
float spacingAddition = 0;
boolean includePadding = false;

StaticLayout myStaticLayout = new StaticLayout(text, myTextView.getPaint(), myTextView.getWidth(), alignment, spacingMultiplier, spacingAddition, includePadding);

float height = myStaticLayout.getHeight();
```

Then you can compare the height of your text and height of your TextView and figure out if it will require scrolling or not.

You can also try to manually create a Paint object with your min text size if `myTextView.getPaint()` approach does not work.

Comment: Thank you, will try that asap.

Comment: Using a `StaticLayout` was the way to go in my case, that is to create an artificial text mass and comparing it to the provided area after rendering. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is put the textview inside a scrollview like so:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test texts here"/>
</ScrollView>
```

In your activity, execute these lines:

```
boolean needScrolling = false;
if(scroller.getHeight() < tv_content.getHeight()) needScrolling = true;
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that asap.

Comment: `tv_content.getHeight()` will always be the same as `scroller.getHeight()`. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No its not. TextView's height is set to wrap_content. If you have short text, they will be the same because of fillViewPort property.

Comment: It is possible that I forgot to set `wrap_content` on the `TextView`. Will try that again. Thank you.

Comment: i believe you may needto take into consideration the textview's top and bottom padding, if applicable

Answer (score 1):

Calculate `mTextView`'s height without data and with data and then compare it

```
mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int lineHeight=mTextView.getCompoundPaddingBottom()+ mTextView.getCompoundPaddingTop()+mTextView.getLineHeight();
            int height=mTextView.getHeight()-(mTextView.getCompoundPaddingTop()+mTextView.getLineHeight());
            if (height>lineHeight){

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that asap.

Comment: Well, `height` will always be greater than `lineheight`, obviously, but that doesn't mean that the `TextView` won't fit its container, therefore require scrolling. Am I missing something? Testing this code fails.